# React Native Async Storage initial state an Array

Tags: react-native, asyncstorage

Hello im new to react native and i want to save datas in my mobile locale storage, I use async storage for storing the data, the data that im sending is an object and i want to store it in an array. So the data that i have been created will store permanently in an Array.

This is the data that i sent

```
    const createMessage = () => {

            const formData = {
                judul,
                deskripsi,
                startDate,
                endDate,
                type
            };
            storeMessage(formData)
    };
```

this is the storage and how to get the data

```
export const storeMessage = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify(value)
    await AsyncStorage.multiSet('MESSAGE_DATA', [jsonValue])
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}

export const getMessage = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('MESSAGE_DATA')
    jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    console.log('value', jsonValue)
    return jsonValue
  } catch (e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

And the getMessage return this data
{"_U": 0, "_V": 0, "_W": null, "_X": null}

How should I call my storage data

Answer (score 0):

```
export const storeMessage = async (value) => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = JSON.stringify([value])
    await AsyncStorage.multiSet('MESSAGE_DATA', jsonValue)
  } catch (e) {
    // saving error
  }
}

export const getMessage = async () => {
  try {
    const jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('MESSAGE_DATA')
    jsonValue != null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
    console.log('value', jsonValue)
    return jsonValue
  } catch (e) {
    // error reading value
  }
}
```

this is the way to do it and the message you getting is because your function is async so you need to use the await for it to return data call it like this

```
const data = await getMessage();
```

Comment: Im using typescript btw, 
const data = await getMessage(); This one didn't work, because I call it on the screen, and await need a function like this

function = async () =>{

Answer (score 0):

multiset and setItem are different.

You are using multiset + getItem, which means you are not getting the correct pair.

##### MultiSet and MultiGet

multi set a key pair values, specified by an array of values.

```
const firstPair = ["@MyApp_user", "value_1"]
const secondPair = ["@MyApp_key", "value_2"]
await AsyncStorage.multiSet([firstPair, secondPair])
```

If you use multiset then you need to use multiget to get the value.

```
const values = await AsyncStorage.multiGet(['@MyApp_user', '@MyApp_key'])
```

##### setItem and getItem

If you want to use getItem,then it must be used with setItem, together with JSON.stringify and JSON.parse

setItem

```
await AsyncStorage.multiSet('MESSAGE_DATA', JSON.stringify(value))
```

getItem

```
let jsonValue = await AsyncStorage.getItem('MESSAGE_DATA')
jsonValue = jsonValue !== null ? JSON.parse(jsonValue) : null;
```

Comment: Yes, thats work, But how I make the Async Storage initial state an array, the data should be looks like this
[
{
  title: 'test'
  description : 'aa'
},
{
 title: 'test',
 description: 'test'
}
]

Comment: at the place where you need the value, check if `AsyncStorage.getItem()` value is null, if's null, return `[...initial value...]`

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to tell you that this is my function to save the data 
```
const createMessage = () => {

            const formData = {
                judul,
                deskripsi,
                startDate,
                endDate,
                type
            };
            storeMessage(formData)
    };
```
If I click the button it always replacing the value and not adding the new data.

Comment: because you didn't merge the array... you should be doing something like `[...oldValue, newValue]` so the new message is append to the array. AsyncStorage is not intelligent, it writes whatever string is given to it. So you need to prepare your own array/object